# Issue with Ember Model promises

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I'm trying to do some basic stuff with Ember Model but I'm experiencing some weird behaviors with promises. Not sure I understand very well how it's supposed to work.

So, I have this route:

```
App.ProfilesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend {

  redirect: ->
    App.Profile.fetch().then (profiles) ->
      console.log profiles.get('length')
      @transitionTo 'profile', profiles.get('firstObject')

}
```

I simply want people to be redirected to `/profiles/123` (= the first profile) when they access `/profiles`.

Here is the Profile adapter:

```
App.Profile.adapter = Ember.Adapter.create {

  findAll: (klass, records) ->
    $.ajax('/api/users/' + $.cookie('user_id'), {
      type: 'get'
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        'Authentication-Token': $.cookie('token')
      }
      dataType: 'json'
    }).then (res) ->
      profiles = []
      // some stuff done here
      records.load klass, profiles

}
```

When I go to `/profiles`, here is what I see in my console:

```
0
Transitioned into 'profiles.index'
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/api/users/456".
```

`0` is the result of `console.log profiles.get('length')`. It seems that it's called before the AJAX call had the chance to finish. What I should have in my console is something like this:

```
Transitioned into 'profiles.index'
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/api/users/456". 
5
```

What am I doing wrong here? Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348945/switch-from-ember-data-fixtureadapter-to-ember-model-fixtureadapter) suggested me to use `fetch` instead of `find` but it doesn't seem to solve my problem because things are not executed in the right order.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to solve the problem thanks to [this jsFiddle by Erik Bryn](http://jsfiddle.net/Ypv6R/2/).

I was missing a `return` here:

```
App.Profile.adapter = Ember.Adapter.create {

  findAll: (klass, records) ->
    $.ajax('/api/users/' + $.cookie('user_id'), {
      type: 'get'
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        'Authentication-Token': $.cookie('token')
      }
      dataType: 'json'
    }).then (res) ->
      profiles = []
      // some stuff done here
      records.load klass, profiles
      return records // HERE

}
```

Also, I now use the `init` method in my `ProfilesIndexRoute` instead of `redirect`:

```
App.ProfilesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend {

  init: ->
    App.Profile.fetch().then (profiles) =>
      @transitionTo 'profile', profiles.get('firstObject')

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect to a different route from the `afterModel` hook:

```
App.ProfilesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend {

  model: ->
    App.Profile.fetch()

  afterModel: (profiles, transition) =>
    @transitionTo 'profile', profiles.get('firstObject')

}
```

Furthermore since you are using `@` you should use the fat arrow `=>` to have the correct reference to `this`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the way you are overring the adapter is wrong:

You are using the jquery ajax deferred. But I think that you need to [wrap that call in RSVP](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/blob/master/packages/ember-model/lib/rest_adapter.js#L127). Because ember use the RSVP to handle promisses.

Give a look in that implementation

```
App.Profile.adapter = Ember.Adapter.create({
    ajaxSettings: function(url, method) {
        return {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                'Authentication-Token': $.cookie('token')
            },
            dataType: "json"
        };
    },
    findAll: function(klass, records) {
        var url = '/api/users/' + $.cookie('user_id'),
        self = this;

        return this.ajax(url).then(function(data) {
            self.didFindAll(klass, records, data);
            return records;
        });
    }   
});
```

I used the `findAll` implementation from [RESTAdapter](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/blob/master/packages/ember-model/lib/rest_adapter.js#L23) and just changed the url, to match what you want.

But if your response return just one object, I think that `find` method is better:

```
...
find: function(record, id) {
    var url = '/api/users/' + $.cookie('user_id'),
        self = this;

    return this.ajax(url).then(function(data) {
      self.didFind(record, id, data);
      return record;
    });
},
...
```